# plot line, combine graphics and Plot in Maxwell distribution

Tags: plotting, graphics

i'm trying to plot Maxwell distribution and draw a line where average speed varg, most probable speed vm, and rms speed vrms, and label those lines.

my struggle how to plot these lines and combine graphics with plot in Show.

**here is the code easy and short!**

```
k = 1.38064852*10^(-23);
m = 28*1.660538782*10^(-27);
t = 300;

max[v_] := ((m/2 Pi k t)^3/2 )*(4 Pi v^2) Exp[-((m*v^2)/(2 k t))]


p1 = Plot[max[v], {v, 0, 1200}]

vm = Sqrt[2 k t/m]
vrms = Sqrt[3 k t/ m]
vavg = Sqrt[8/Pi]*Sqrt[k t /m]

l1 = Graphics[Line[{vm, 0}, {vm, y}]]
l2 = Line[{0, vrms}]
l3 = Line[{0, vavg}]

Show[p1, l1]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you defined $y$?  With no $y$ yet defined, `l1 = Graphics[Line[{vm, 0}, {vm, y}]]` will not be well defined.

Comment: Note the syntax for `Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]`: you are missing a set of braces; you should also probably use `InfiniteLine` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your definitions, consider something like this:

```
l1 = InfiniteLine[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}] &[vm];
l2 = InfiniteLine[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}] &[vrms];
l3 = InfiniteLine[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}] &[vavg];

Show[
 p1,
 Graphics[{Red, l1, Blue, l2, Black, l3}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One might also consider using `GridLines`.

Comment: how do i label them !?

Answer (score 2):

Your definition for `max` is not a valid `PDF`

```
max[v_] := ((m/2 Pi k t)^3/2)*(4 Pi v^2) Exp[-((m*v^2)/(2 k t))]
```

The total probability should be `1`

```
Assuming[m > 0 && k > 0 && t > 0,
 Integrate[max[v], {v, 0, Infinity}]]

(* (m^(3/2) π^(9/2) (k t)^(9/2))/(4 Sqrt[2]) *)
```

You probably intended to use

```
max[v_] := (m/(2 Pi k t))^(3/2)*(4 Pi v^2) Exp[-((m*v^2)/(2 k t))]
```

This is a valid `PDF`

```
Assuming[m > 0 && k > 0 && t > 0,
 Integrate[max[v], {v, 0, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)
```

You would be better off using the built-in [`MaxwellDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxwellDistribution.html)

```
dist = MaxwellDistribution[Sqrt[k t/m]];
```

This has the same `PDF` as the revised `max`

```
Assuming[m > 0 && k > 0 && t > 0 && v > 0,
 PDF[dist, v] == max[v] // Simplify]

(* True *)

vavg = Mean[dist]

(* 2 Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[(k t)/m] *)

vrms = RootMeanSquare[dist]

(* Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(k t)/m] *)
```

The mode is

```
vm = v /. Solve[{D[PDF[dist, v], v] == 0 && 
    m > 0 && k > 0 && t > 0 && v > 0}, v][[1]] // 
  Simplify[#, m > 0 && k > 0 && t > 0] &

(* Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(k t)/m] *)
```

Comment: Additionally, the "magic constants" in the OP are `k = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"]]]` and `m = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[28, "AtomicMassUnit"]]]`.

Comment: Thanks guys so much